# Type of p value to select from those given by software

Tags: p-value

I'm a medical student and pretty new to statistics, struggling with some things.
I am currently undertaking a research project on dilated kidneys in foetuses and the outcome in childhood. I have some very basics statistics to start with

**e.g.** 
Proportions:
53 patients.
39 (73.6%) - Male.
14 (26.4%) - Female.

I am using `statsdirect` software which produces both '**exact** (clopper-pearson) 95% confidence intervals' with binomial two sided **p values**, and '**approximate** (wilson) 95% **mid-P** confidence intervals' with binomial two sided **mid-p values**.

Which do I use? for this particular statistic there is very little difference, but for others in the project one can be <0.05 and one >0.05 - making the difference in how I write about my results.

If I use one, do I then have to use this for each remaining p value in the project?

Comment: You might find some of the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) helpful for choosing between them.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, there is no *type* of *p*-value. Rather, these are *p*-values (i.e. *probabilities* of observing the value of your test statistic if the null hypothesis is true) corresponding to different types of test statistics.

'Exact' test statistics are calculated so as to exactly correspond to the distribution implied by one's null hypothesis, whereas 'approximate' test statistics are generally easier to calculate, but may only be appropriate—that is: they may only give values reasonably close to the exact statistics—for large samples (where "large" depends on the distribution of the specific test statistic in question).

Comment: But google for "approximate better than exact"

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen 
 
From my understanding "approximate p-values" are just "exact p-values" of a test statistic from a distribution which is argued to approximate the (perhaps usually discrete) exact distribution of a researcher's interest. The "approximate" in such a case is about the distribution of the actual test statistic being used. One still obtains the p-value from an application the CDF, whether or not the test is approximate or exact, right?

Answer (score 1):

See Clopper-Pearson Interval in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper-Pearson_interval

I will go ahead and highlight some points from that [section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Clopper-Pearson_interval) with some re-wording

> Clopper-Pearson interval never has less than the nominal coverage (i.e. the actual probability that the interval contains the true statistic value of interest, which is often set at 0.95) for any population proportion, but that means that it is usually conservative (i.e. when the actual confidence interval is greater than the nominal coverage probability).
>
> > For example, the true coverage rate (or confidence level) of a 95% Clopper-Pearson interval may be well above 95%, depending on the nunmber of trials and the binomial random variable. Thus the interval may be wider than it needs to be to achieve 95% confidence.
> >
> > > In contrast, other confidence bounds such as the **Wilson Interval** may be narrower than their nominal confidence where a nominal coverage of 95% may in fact cover less than 95%. ***Hence, the discrepancy you noticed between their reported p-values.***

**In conclusion,** I suggest, you choose one interval, and use it throughout the project in reporting the p-value results, only state clearly the interval of choice used (and if possible, why).

Answer (score 0):

The exact p value is the p value for a test that meets certain assumptions while the approximate p value is less strict. What would be the way to go is check which test you are doing (probably proportional z test) and check which assumptions this test has and if your data meets them.

What are you testing by the way? If there is a difference between male and female patients in proportional outcome?